# How can I convert images to textures?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this script but I'm not sure how to convert the info array to textures and assign the info images to the textures array.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class StreamVideo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture[] frames;                // array of textures
    public float framesPerSecond = 2.0f;    // delay between frames
    public RawImage image;

    void Start()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\tmp");
        string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".JPG", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".png", ".PNG", ".ogg", ".OGG" };
        FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();

        if (image == null)
        {
            //Get Raw Image Reference
            image = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        int index = (int)(Time.time * framesPerSecond) % frames.Length;
        image.texture = frames[index]; //Change The Image
    }
}
```

Then I copied the images from the tmp folder to my project new folder but if I select all the images in the assets I can't drag them to the inspector of the script I can only drag them one by one and it will take time so how can I do it with the script ?

Comment: Either way you should not do it in Update ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would need to read the according file e.g. using [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes)

Then you could use [`ImageConversion.LoadImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html)

I would then do the entire loading process already on app start and later only exchange the texture like e.g.

```
public class StreamVideo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture[] frames;                // array of textures
    public float framesPerSecond = 2.0f;    // delay between frames
    public RawImage image;

    void Start()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\tmp");
        // since you use ToLower() the capitalized version are quite redundant btw ;)
        string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".ogg" };
        FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();

        if (!image)
        {
            //Get Raw Image Reference
            image = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
        }

        frames = GetTextures(infos);
    }

    private Texture[] GetTextures(FileInfo[] fileInfos)
    {
        var output = new Texture[fileInfos.Length];
        for(var i = 0; i < fileInfos.Length; i++)
        {
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfos[i].fullName);
            output[i] = new Texture2D(1,1);
            if(!ImageConversion.LoadImage(output[i], bytes, false))
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Could not load image from {fileInfos.Length}!", this);
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        int index = (int)(Time.time * framesPerSecond) % frames.Length;
        image.texture = frames[index]; //Change The Image
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Derhugo is that a fine way to load many images to raimage one by one making video effect ? I have now 120 images but if ihad 500 for example ? The problem with the video player of unity is when looping it need each time to prepare the player and that make 1 second delay each time it start playing over again.

Comment: In general I'ld say it's fine but ofcourse loading 500 external images will take quite a time so you might want to consider to rather to it all `async` and show a loading screen meanwhile

Comment: @derHugo It's working great still a small delay very small delay when it's starting over again in the Update I wonder if there is a way to avoid this delay ? It's almost smooth. Like a millisecond of delay or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag multiple selected images.
First you need to lock your inspector view with a padlock (not possible if you skip that).
Then select all the images, and drop then onto the *name_of_the_array* (not, into the field). This is just a matter of getting the drag mechanic right, nothing else.

Also, fileinfo reference in your question is a bit confusing, as you are not doing anything with the result anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have not done that myself yet, but I believe that should work with:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html
In the code example there, insteed of "imageAsset.bytes", apply this function to your files (calling FullPath on your FileInfo instances):
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.File.ReadAllBytes.html